# Add plugin in Internet Explorer manually

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In Google Chrome, we can add a plugin by go on Plugin manager, add just drag and drop a plugin folder (with JavaScript, manifest Inside) for add and use a custom plugin.

I wonder if it is possible to perform the same operation with Internet Explorer 11.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Hum, ty. I've already gone on this link, but can't found Plugins folder in location. I added it manually, but I do not know if it works.